# Points to a 1km x 1km cell grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-statistics, point, aggregate-points

I have a large database of point data throughout all of Eastern Australia. Each point represents species presence/absence data and has attached about 18 predictor variables. To account for sampling intensity, I would like to make a 1km x 1km grid and count the frequency of the number of presence records (this would be my response variable) and create another column in the data frame that is the sum of all points within the cell (this would become an offset variable in a GLMM).

What is the best approach to this problem? I know of the [Point to Raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/point-to-raster.htm) tool, however I dont think it allows for keeping the other predictor variables. [Aggregate Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/aggregate-points.htm) is another option, however I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and I dont have access to the [ArcGIS GeoAnalytics Server](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/what-is-arcgis-geoanalytics-server-.htm).

Comment: Create a fishnet (1k x 1k) covering your area of interest and then overlay your fishnet over your points (spatial join) then you can use summary statistics with your polygon ID as a case field to find statistics per grid cell.

Comment: You are referencing the documentation of two ArcGIS Pro tools but appear to be using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.  Both tools exist in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 but Aggregate Points in that architecture has less functionality.